# Why aren't my words coming out less than 8 characters?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

```
public String compWord() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    // Local constants
    final int MAX_COUNT = 8;

    // Local variables
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dictionary.txt"));       // Create a new BufferedReader, looking for dictionary.txt
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();                                       // New ArrayList to keep track of the lines
    String line;                                                                        // Current line
    Random rand = new Random();                                                         // New random object
    String word;                                                                        // The computer's word

    /********************* Start compWord *********************/

    // Start reading the txt file
    line = reader.readLine();

    // WHILE the line isn't null
    while(line != null)
    {
        // Add the line to lines list
        lines.add(line);

        // Go to the next line
        line = reader.readLine();
    }

    // Set the computers word to a random word in the list
    word = lines.get(rand.nextInt(lines.size()));

    if(word.length() > MAX_COUNT)
        compWord();

    // Return the computer's word
    return word;
}
```

From what I understand it should only be returning words less than 8 characters? Any idea what I am doing wrong? The if statement should recall compWord until the word is less than 8 characters. But for some reason I'm still get words from 10-15 chars.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at this code:

```
if(word.length() > MAX_COUNT)
    compWord();

return word;
```

If the word that is picked is longer than your limit, you're calling `compWord` recursively - but ignoring the return value, and just returning the "too long" word anyway.

Personally I would suggest that you avoid the recursion, and instead just use a `do`/`while` loop:

```
String word;
do
{
    word = lines.get(rand.nextInt(lines.size());
} while (word.length() > MAX_COUNT);
return word;
```

Alternatively, filter *earlier* while you read the lines:

```
while(line != null) {
    if (line.length <= MAX_COUNT) { 
        lines.add(line);
    }
    line = reader.readLine();
}
return lines.get(rand.nextInt(lines.size()));
```

That way you're only picking out of the valid lines to start with.

Note that using `Files.readAllLines` is a rather simpler way of reading all the lines from a text file, by the way - and currently you're not closing the file afterwards...

Comment: But shouldn't compWord start again before it even returns anything?

Comment: @tdrunner95: Yes, it starts again, picks a random word, possibly recursing yet again, then returns a word. You then ignore that return value, and return whatever was first picked. I think you need to read up on recursion a bit...

Comment: Thanks. My prof barely touched on recursion. I'll look into it more.

Comment: @tdrunner95: Well recursion is what you're currently doing, but this problem really doesn't call for recursion. You should try to understand why your current code doesn't work - but then solve the problem a different way rather than making the recursive form work.

Answer (score 0):

If the word is longer than 8 characters, you simply call your method again, continue, and nothing changes.

So:

- You are getting all the words from the file,
- Then getting a random word from the List, and putting it in the `word` String,
- And if the word is is longer than 8 characters, the method runs again.
- **But**, at the end, it will *always* return the word it picked first. The problem is that you just call the method recursively, and you do nothing with the return value. You are calling a method, and it will do something, and the caller method will continue, and in this case return your `word`. It does not matter if this method is recursive or not.

Instead, I would recommend you use a non-recursive solution, as Skeet recommended, or learn a bit about recursion and how to use it.